# Xamarin c# - Apps aren't starting

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I installed Xamarin on VS to make android apps with c#. Everything is good configured (I think so).
[configuration of my sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb4uy.png)

After creating a new project and selecting to run sample app on my avd (5.0 API21). AVD starts but my app doesn't appear. Also when i copy signed file to my Android phone (5.0.1 API21) it says "app is stopped"
After waiting i've got but deploy is checked...

```
The application could not be started. Ensure that the application has been installed to the target device and has a launchable activity (MainLauncher = true).

Additionally, check Build->Configuration Manager to ensure this project is set to Deploy for this configuration.
```

My code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
        }
```

Comment: Have you set MainLauncher=true ?

Comment: Yes... it was already

Comment: AVDs are generally slow. Did you wait for some time after AVD got loaded ?  It is generally recommended to use Xamarin Android Player or other emulators like Genymotion instead of AVDs because of this reason.

Comment: Yes, i waited and i've got "The application could not be started. Ensure that the application has been installed to the target device and has a launchable activity (MainLauncher = true).

Additionally, check Build->Configuration Manager to ensure this project is set to Deploy for this configuration." but deploy is checked.

Comment: Did you try deleting the App from AVD and then cleaning the solution and re-deploy ?

Comment: I can't find my app in avd

Comment: Do you deploy a debug-build? Is Visual Studio configured to deploy the shared runtime to the target device?

Comment: Changing APi to 4.4 resolved problem!

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the following is above the MainActivity class

```
[Activity(Label = "YourAppName", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```